# Problems instantiating object to a specific object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create multiple references to an Object called `Ball` so that there will be multiple balls on screen when it is time for such action. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Here is how I am trying to accomplish this:

```
private GameObject reference;
private Ball[] ballArray;
void Start () {
    reference = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ball");
    ballArray = new Ball[amountOfBalls - 1];
    start = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < ballArray.Length + 1; i++)
    {
        ballArray[i] = Instantiate(reference);
        print("Initialized: " + (i + 1) + " times.");
    }
}
```

When I do this I get the following error:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'Ball'`

However, if I change the type of `ballArray` to `Object` it works and throws no errors, however I can't access the methods of `Ball` if it is of type `Object`. And I need the methods.

How can I make this work and still have access to my `Ball` class methods?

Here is an example to further clarify what I need to be able to do:

```
void Update () {
    for (int i = 0; i < ballArray.Length + 1; i++) {

        if (ballArray[i].isOffScreen()) {
            print("Ball #" + (i+1) + " is off screen");
        }
    }
}
```

I need to be able to access the `isOffScreen` method from the `Ball` class.

Comment: What's wrong with `ballArray[i] = new Ball();`?

Comment: @Idos No. In unity you can't do that if your class inherits from Monobehaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate and store the GameObject to a temporary GameObject then use `GetComponent` to get the instance of that Ball script attached to it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ballArray.Length; i++)
{
    GameObject tempObj = (GameObject)Instantiate(reference);
    ballArray[i] = tempObj.GetComponent<Ball>();
}
```

This solves

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'Ball'

error.

You have been corrected in your last question. Please stop doing this: `ballArray = new Ball[amountOfBalls - 1];`. Simple do `ballArray = new Ball[amountOfBalls];`

For your update code, use the following code:

```
void Update () {
  for (int i = 0; i < ballArray.Length; i++) 
   {
        if (ballArray[i].isOffScreen()) {
            print("Ball #" + (i+1) + " is off screen");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I removed all the `for (int i = 0; i < ballArray.Length + 1; i++)` from both code blocks and replaced them with `for (int i = 0; i < ballArray.Length; i++)`. That's the right way to do this.

Comment: @Luke Updated my answer.

Comment: Jesus, how many times are you gonna save me. Excellent, exactly what I needed. Perfect job.

Comment: @Luke As long as I am online can answer it, I would. And please stop doing 1ballArray = new Ball[amountOfBalls - 1];`. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You could change datatype of ballArray to

```
List<GameObject> ballArray = new List<GameObject>();
```

So to call the isOffScreen method,

```
ballArray[i].getComponent<Ball>().isOffScreen()
```

**Updated**

End Result

```
private GameObject reference;
private List<GameObject> ballArray;
void Start()
{
    reference = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ball");
    ballArray = new List<GameObject>();
    start = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfBalls; i++)
    {
        ballArray.Add(Instantiate(reference));
        print("Initialized: " + (i + 1) + " times.");

        if (ballArray[i].GetComponent<Ball>().IsOffScreen())
        {
            print("Ball #" + (i + 1) + " is off screen");
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @CloudSL You should't do `ballArray[i] = ballArray[i].getComponent<Ball>().isOffScreen()` without initializing`ballArray`. You will get `Null Exception` error thrown at you. You have to do `ballArray[i].getComponent<Ball>()` then assign it to `ballArray[i]` before accessing `isOffScreen()`. For example `ballArray[i] = ballArray[i].getComponent<Ball>()`. Now you can do  `ballArray[i].isOffScreen()` or `ballArray[i] = ballArray[i].getComponent<Ball>().isOffScreen()` if you like redundancy.